# Shortcuts for next perfect power computation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

The answers in [Given an integer, how can I detect the nearest integer perfect power efficiently?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298044/) show two effective algorithms for computing the nearest [perfect power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) for a given integer $n$, although they can be improved by checking only prime exponents.

My algorithm for computing the next perfect power $\mathrm{np}(n)$
greater than or equal an integer $n\ge 8$ basically
minimizes $d(n,p) = \lceil n^{1/p} \rceil ^p - n$
for all  primes $p \le \log_2 n+2.$

If $d(n,p)=0$  (or $\lceil n^{1/p} \rceil =1 $) during the prime loop, the required power is obviously found and we are done.
But due to [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (or Mihăilescu's theorem) we can do better
and stop if $d(n,p) < 2.$

Since the next perfect power is in most cases $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil ^2$,
the following question arises:

> Are there other shortcuts or conditions to detect $\mathrm{np}(n)=\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil ^2$ without computing $d(n,p)$ for primes $p>2?$ Are there more Mihăilescu type shortcuts?

Comment: this is the limit $O(\ln n)$ , i don't think you could improve this any further.