# How to find the closest representation $N = n^a$ for some integer $N$?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, logarithms, arithmetic, exponentiation

To find the closest representation $n^a$ for some positive integer $N$ we just bruteforce all the logs: $\log_2 N$, $\log_3 N$, ...  and compare all the results to determine which one is the closest.

**For example,** how to find the closest $N = n^a$ for $N$ = 127:

The first check: $\log_2 127= 7$ gives us a very close $n^a$ which is $128$, but how do we know it's the closest one, without checking other possible $n^a$ ?

#### Question 1:

- Do we have to use described above bruteforce method to find $n^a$ the closest to some $N$ ?

  for example: $N = 2403$, do we just bruteforce and compare all the logs up until $\log_7$ at which point we find that the  $\log_7 2403 = 4$ is the closest possible $N = n^a$ for $N = 2403$ ?

#### Question 2:

- How would we find not just the closest $N = n^a$ but the closest $N = n^a + m^b$ (let's use the same integer $N = 2403$ for the example) ?

Comment: for your example $5^3$ gives us the closest integer power to $124$.

Comment: for the first question this is true, there is no faster algorithm, for the second question it is very hard because odd power can be negative also widen the net of search in two square could be the closest so at least you need $O(\sqrt{n})$ algorithm and if allowed negative integer for odd powers its very hard problem, may be there is a fast way to do it.

Comment: @Ahmad oh, you're right, I was thinking about $127$ but wrote $124$ for some reason. What if in the second question we limit $n,m,a,b$ to be in range $1-99$ is there a way to easily do it then?

Comment: Well the closest always is $n=N$, $a=1$ :)

Comment: @orlp sure is. Not much helpful though :)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425003/shortcuts-for-next-perfect-power-computation and the link in the question

Answer (score 2):

Rather than looking at bases, look at exponents.

Start with $a = \lceil\log_2(n)\rceil$. This is the highest interesting exponent. Then for each integer exponent at and below that calculate $[N^{-a}]^a$, where $[x]$ is $x$ rounded to the nearest integer.

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example, though? So for the $N=2400$ I define $a_{max}=12$ and then what do I do with exponents $12,11,10...$? $(2400^{-12})^{12}$ is just $0$ how does it get me from $a_{max}=12$ to the $7^4$ (which is the closest $n^a$ to $2400$) ?