# What power of a number is closest to a given integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Lets say there is a positive number (integer) given ($N$). What should be the simplest way to find the $K^p$ (where $K$ and $p$ both $>1$) which is closest to $N$ amongst all the possible combinations of $K$ and $p$?

When we say closest, it means the difference between $N$ and $K^p$ is less than any other possible combination of $K$ and $p$.

Example:
If $N=25$ then $5^2$ is the closest solution. If $N=150$ then $12^2$ is the closest you can get to $N$. And so on.

Comment: why downvote? This is unfair.

Comment: Please use MathJax/LaTeX for matting, there are links in the help center to get you started. One of your examples is, $5^5=3125$ that's not close to $25$, but as you haven't ruled out $p=1$ the (trivial) solution of $K=N$ and $p=1$ works.

Comment: Okay.. I have made corrections. Definitely, p should be > 1 otherwise question is pointless. But anyways, thanks I will make the changes.

Comment: To make your formatting come out looking like math, enclose the math expressions in `$` signs, not backquotes.

Comment: @khan It is a duplicate (I did not downvote/closevote however!) I remember this question and suggested a method very similar to the one Gerry mentions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298044/given-an-integer-how-can-i-detect-the-nearest-integer-perfect-power-efficiently/2219230#2219230

Answer (score 2):

Most perfect powers are squares, so a good way would be to find $a$ such that $a^2\le N\le (a+1)^2$, and then test all the numbers between $a^2$ and $(a+1)^2$ to see whether there are any perfect powers there.

Another way is to first calculate the integer part $k$ of $\log_2N$, so you know that (in your notation) $k+1$ is an upper bound for the $p$ you are looking for. Then you can calculate $N^{1/r}$ (or $(1/r)\log N$) for $2\le r\le k+1$ and pick out the best answer.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this apparently can be a way.